# How to pass more than 1 array to ArrayAdapterView

Tags: android, listview

I want to pass multiple arrays in adapter view in my project.

I did it like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView lv = getListView();
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, COUNTRIES));
```

But I want to pass one more array, name as a people, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

if you pass the more than 1 value in adapter ...

1)create getter and setter method..for each item you pass...

ex:

```
public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
```

2)create object for store data..

ex:

```
obj.setTitle("value");
```

3)create arrayList for store object....

```
ArrayList<News> arrList = new ArrayList<News>();
arrList.add(obj);
```

4)pass arraylist into custom adapter....

better way to pass more than one value...it's work..